# Commits are not showing in the profile, tried everything

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, github-for-windows

I am having trouble with Github commit. I have tried all the commands and everything seems fine. I am able to push the progress in the repo but it does not show in the profile. However, whenever I do git push
response is Password for 'https://username@github.com': XXX
this is not my email address, I think it might be the issue.

I have used the commands git config --global user.email and the email under this is right as well.

I am certain that there is an issue with the local pc, because when I create an issue on git website it reflects the contribution in the profile.

Any help would be great.

thanks

```
git config --global user.name
CorrectUsername

git config --global user.email
CorrectEmail@correctdomain

git config --unset --global user.name

git config --unset --global user.email

git config --unset user.name

git config --unset user.email

git remote rm origin

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/CorrectRepo/CorrectRepo.git

git config user.name "CorrectUsername"

git config user.email "CorrectEmail"

git config --global user.name "CorrectUsername"

git config --global user.email "CorrectUsername@correctdomain"

git config --list
```

Answer (score 1):

'https://username@github.com' this is not your email address it is asking for [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) for the `username`.

```
git init
git add .
git config --global user.name "Username"
git config --global user.email "Email"
git branch -M [branch name] # example 'main' or 'master'
git remote add origin [repository url]
git commit -m "Update"
git push
```

Then enter your username name and personal Access Token

1. Click Settings icon in the user bar
2. click  Developer settings.
3. click Personal access tokens.
4. Click Generate new token.

Don't use force option `git push -f origin main` it will remove all previous commits.

Use

```
git push

# or

git push -U origin main
```

Comment: Thanks for the output man. Yes, I know that "https://username@github.com" is not my username. I used "username" to hide my actual username. I already use an access token to push code onto GitHub. But, none of my contributions shows up in the GitHub contribution chart.

To push onto GitHub, I use git push. Previously, I have done the process as you mentioned in your post but did not resolve the issue.

Let me know if you know of any potential solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see this https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

Comment: has this being fixed